# Concave header which stays at top when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I've found a lot of options to have a curved header on the net, some which are concave.

This is the effect I want to get, however I want to be able to keep the header on top, even when scrolling through a list.

[image]

This is the codepen I found and slightly adapted, but it doesn't keep the header on top:

https://codepen.io/rept/pen/XWWeBoE

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 256px;
  background: #2a6a8d;
  font-family: Arial Narrow;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e7eeff;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>- Content 1</li>
    <li>- Content 2</li>
    <li>- Content 3</li>
    <li>- Content 4</li>
    <li>- Content 5</li>
    <li>- Content 6</li>
    <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:sticky` and do the curve differently to make it a part of the title.

Here is an idea using multiple background:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 256px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 98%,#2a6a8d 100%) bottom right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%,#2a6a8d 100%) bottom left , 
    #2a6a8d content-box;
  background-size:30px 30px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
  padding-bottom:30px;
  margin-bottom:-30px;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e7eeff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>- Content 1</li>
    <li>- Content 2</li>
    <li>- Content 3</li>
    <li>- Content 4</li>
    <li>- Content 5</li>
    <li>- Content 6</li>
    <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 6</li>
    <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and integrates easily in my existing template since it's part of the header element!

Answer (score 2):

Your content should be scrollable inside to achieve what you want.

What I added is this

```
max-height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
```

You should adjust max-height to your needs.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 256px;
  background: #2a6a8d;
  font-family: Arial Narrow;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.content { 
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e7eeff;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>- Content 1</li>
    <li>- Content 2</li>
    <li>- Content 3</li>
    <li>- Content 4</li>
    <li>- Content 5</li>
    <li>- Content 6</li>
    <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
     <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
     <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've marked your answer useful.  This indeed solves the scolling. For my use case it's even better if that's part of the header.

Comment: awesome! There you go. Happy coding )

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 256px;
  background: #2a6a8d;
  font-family: Arial Narrow;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #e7eeff;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>- Content 1</li>
    <li>- Content 2</li>
    <li>- Content 3</li>
    <li>- Content 4</li>
    <li>- Content 5</li>
    <li>- Content 6</li>
    <li>- Content 7</li>
    <li>- Content 8</li>
    <li>- Content 9</li>
    <li>- Content 10</li>
    <li>- Content 11</li>
    <li>- Content 12</li>
    <li>- Content 13</li>
    <li>- Content 14</li>
    <li>- Content 15</li>
    <li>- Content 16</li>
    <li>- Content 17</li>
    <li>- Content 18</li>
    <li>- Content 19</li>
    <li>- Content 20</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```